# Hyperlink in TextBlock is is not clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I have made this in code-behind :

```
var finishedText = new Run("Some text");
var finishedUrl = new Run("http://somewhere");

var hyperlink = new Hyperlink(finishedUrl) { NavigateUri = new Uri("http://somewhere") };

hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedText);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedUrl);
```

In XAML :

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           x:Name="FinishedTextBlock"
           Width="Auto"
           Margin="10 10 0 0">
</TextBlock>
```

The text is not clickable.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF, but [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink?view=netcore-3.1#examples) wraps it in a paragraph. I don't know if that makes a difference though.

Comment: Isn't the property that sets the url of a HyperLink `NavigateUrl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The text is not clickable.

That is because your `Hyperlink` text is not even shown. You see the last `Run` that you have added to the `Inlines` collection, not the hyperlink itself.

You add the same `Run` named `finishedUrl` to your `Hyperlink` and its containing `TextBlock`, but you have to create a separate `Run` instance for the `Hyperlink`.

```
var finishedText = new Run("Some text");
var finishedUrl = "http://somewhere";
var finishedUrlRun = new Run(finishedUrl);

var hyperlink = new Hyperlink(finishedUrlRun) { NavigateUri = new Uri("http://somewhere") };

hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedText);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);

var finishedUrlRun1 = new Run(finishedUrl);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedUrlRun1);
```

Even better, just do not add the last `Run`, as it is redundant, and replace the `NewLine` with a `LineBreak` to get the same layout as in your image but with a link.

```
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedText);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your hyperlink is inside a webview then nothing will happen when you click on a hyperlink.

You need to handle the RequestNavigate event and do something before you'll see a web browser appear with a page in it.

If this was a wpf page inside a frame, or navigationwindow then it would also navigate without code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink?view=netcore-3.1

> **Remarks**

> Hyperlink implements the NavigateUri property that you set
> with the Uri of the content that should be navigated to when the
> Hyperlink is clicked. Hyperlink navigation can only occur, however, if
> either the direct or indirect parent of a Hyperlink is a navigation
> host, including NavigationWindow, Frame, or any browser that can host
> XBAPs (which includes Internet Explorer 6 and later versions, and
> Firefox 2.0+). For more information, see the Navigation Hosts topic in
> Navigation Overview.

As it is, you need an event handler.

I'm not clear whether you intend the url to appear or a string. If you want a different string then this should work:

```
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text="Some text" } );
        tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        Run linkRun = new Run("Link To Google");
        Hyperlink hyper = new Hyperlink(linkRun) { NavigateUri = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com") };
        hyper.RequestNavigate += (o, e) => Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.ToString()){ UseShellExecute = true }); 
        tb.Inlines.Add(hyper);
```

If you want the url to appear rather than some other string then:

```
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "Some text" });
        tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        string url = @"http://www.google.com";
        Run linkRun = new Run(url);
        Hyperlink hyper = new Hyperlink(linkRun){ NavigateUri = new Uri(url) };
        hyper.RequestNavigate += (o, e) => Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.ToString()) { UseShellExecute = true });
        tb.Inlines.Add(hyper);
        sp.Children.Add(tb);
```

**Note**

One the process start, you will often get an error on win 10 machines without that useshellexecute in the process startinfo.

In older OS ( and you would see in old SO answers ) you used to be able to just process start with a URL and it would work with the default browser.

There is a linebreak inline which is intended to add a linebreak between a series of runs in a textblock.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, it needs to be like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="FinishedTextBlock"
    Width="Auto"
    Margin="10 10 0 0">
<Run Text="Some text" /> 
<LineBreak/>
<Hyperlink>http://somewhere</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The hyperlink in your code does not content anything. The hyperlink constructor parameter
[finishedUrl] did not initialized the hyperlink to contain the string "http://somewhere".

You can change your code something like below:

```
var finishedText = new Run("Some text");
var finishedUrl = new Run("http://somewhere");

var hyperlink = new Hyperlink() { NavigateUri = new Uri("http://somewhere") };
hyperlink.Inlines.Add(finishedUrl.Text);

hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(finishedText);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
FinishedTextBlock.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
```